How to design narrow band pass filter with a given phase response at the pass band?
I have been solving a problem from the digital control theory whose solution could be to extract a specific frequency ("very narrow" band with center at the frequency of interest would be sufficient) from the system input and achieve a given phase lead at this frequency. May I ask you for an advice how to design a digital filter which fullfill those requirements? Probably those two requirements can be more easily solved in two filters in cascade. Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Exactly one frequency?  Can't be done, at least in a universe of a finite age -- you need a range.  A (relatively) narrow range of frequencies?  Can be done, but your filter will have tons of phase shift around the frequency in question, which will cause every kind of problem in closed loop.

@TimWescott thank you for your reaction. "Very narrow" band with center at the frequency of interest would be sufficient.

Are you using this in a closed loot system? Because if you are, it will not work.  Your system will end up oscillating somewhere close to, but not exactly on, your narrow band filter's frequency of interest.

It is intended to be used as a part of a feedforward compensation of a periodic disturbance.

Are you asking how to implement a plain old bandpass filter?  If "very narrow" means a very small fraction of your sampling rate, I suggest a standard IIR bandpass filter, probably cascaded with a lowpass, lead-lag, or allpass filter to shift the phase appropriately.  Or get fancy and design your IIR bandpass to inherently have the necessary phase shift.
